# How can I logoff from game center from my app

Tags: objective-c, logout, game-center

i'd like to know a way to logoff from game center from my app, 
i know to authenticate is

```
[[GKLocalPlayer localPlayer] authenticateWithCompletionHandler:nil];
```

is there a similar way to logout?

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I've looked through the developer documentation, and it doesn't look like it.  You could probably find a private API to do it, but then your app would be rejected from the store, rendering Game Center functionality pointless.